# Sniffing packets using tshark

Tags: networking, tcp, wireshark, ethernet, tshark

I have 2 servers(serv1,serv2) that communicate and i'm trying to sniff packets matching certain criteria that gets transferred from serv1 to serv2. Tshark is installed on my Desktop(desk1). I have written the following script:

```
while true; do
tshark -a duration:10 -i eth0  -R "(sip.CSeq.method == "OPTIONS") && (sip.Status-Code) && ip.src eq serv1" -Tfields -e sip.response-time > response.time.`date +%F-%T`
 done
```

This script seems to run fine when run on serv1(since serv1 is sending packets to serv2). However, when i try to run this on desk1, it cant capture any packets. They all are on the same LAN. What am i missing?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that either serv1 or serv2 are on the same physical ethernet switch as desk1, you *can* sniff transit traffic between serv1 and serv2 by using a feature called SPAN (Switch Port Analyzer).

Assume your server is on FastEtheret4/2 and your desktop is on FastEthernet4/3 of the Cisco Switch... you should telnet or ssh into the switch and enter these commands...

```
4507R#configure terminal
Enter configuration commands, one per line. End with CNTL/Z.

4507R(config)#monitor session 1 source interface fastethernet 4/2

!--- This configures interface Fast Ethernet 4/2 as source port.

4507R(config)#monitor session 1 destination interface fastethernet 4/3

!--- The configures interface Fast Ethernet 0/3 as destination port.



4507R#show monitor session 1
Session 1
---------
Type : Local Session
Source Ports :
Both : Fa4/2
Destination Ports : Fa4/3


4507R#
```

This feature is not limited to Cisco devices... Juniper / HP / Extreme and other Enterprise ethernet switch vendors also support it.

Answer (score 1):

How about using the misnamed tcpdump which will capture all traffic from the wire. What I suggest doing is just capturing packets on the interface. Do not filter at the capture level. After you can filter the pcap file. Something like this

```
tcpdump -w myfile.pcap -n -nn -i eth0
```

Comment: the problem is that he is on an ethernet switch.  Additional configuration of said switch is required

Answer (score 0):

If your LAN is a switched network (most are) or your desktop NIC doesn't support promiscuous mode, then you won't be able to see any of the packets.  Verify both of those things.

Comment: Can this be a problem even when the same script, when run on serv1? My initial guess was that -i eth0 would be causing the problem. Does my command look ok?

Comment: Well, the problem of a switched network won't be a factor on serv1, since the packets are intended to flow to/from that machine (so the switch will of course be sending traffic to it).  On desk1, the switch (if it exists) won't recognize your machine as a legitimate receiver of the packets, so won't send them to you.  That is the main difference between running on serv1 and desk1

Comment: This problem has nothing to do with promiscuous mode; if the switch has learned the destination mac-address of the servers, by default ethernet switches only send traffic to the port with that mac-address on it.